# Passing custom object between activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, mqtt, paho

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/swlh/android-and-mqtt-a-simple-guide-cb0cbba1931c) tutorial on how to use MQTT with Android Studio. In it, they created an `MQTTClient` class that uses the [MQTTAndroidClient](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/index.html) library. I want to pass the `MQTTClient` class from one activity to another. Any suggestions how I might do this? I'm new to Android dev and I'm trying to negotiate serializable/parcelable tools without much know-how. Thanks!

P.S. I'm developing in Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing complex classes between activities is generally a bad idea. For that kind of usage you should use a Singleton and store it in your Application class or something like this.

Comment: I'm not familar with Singleton. Where is the variable/object initialized?

Comment: Thank you, using a singleton is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to pass the entire `MQTTClient` through Activities.

I'd suggest you to read this [Dependency-Injection manual](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/manual) is more or less what you need, normally you'd use a [`dependency injection`](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection) library/framework to do what you want but since is complex to set-up most of them I'd follow the link I've linked before.

Sample code :

```
// Container of objects shared across the whole app
class AppContainer {

    val mqttClient = MQTTClient() //<-- Initialisation 
}
```

Then create a custom `Application`

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    // Instance of AppContainer that will be used by all the Activities of the app
    val appContainer = AppContainer()
}
```

Do not forget to add it to `manifest.xml` with the name attribute.

And then from your Activity you need this `MQTTClient` you use :

```
val appContainer = (application as MyApplication).appContainer
val mqttClient = appContainer.mqttClient
```

What @Ben-J suggested is also a good point, to create a [`Singleton`](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-create-a-singleton-class-in-kotlin) in kotlin you can use the `object` keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the singleton is the approach I'll use